# CStdioFile::WriteString adding additional carriage return for line feeds?

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc

I just met the following behaviour: When using `CStdioFile::WriteString`, it will convert a `\n` to `\r\n`.
I didn't note this behaviour in earlier versions of my code, only after I converted my project to Unicode. What am I missing?

I tried this code:

```
        CStdioFile file;
        CFileException fileException;

        file.Open(TEXT("c:\\test.txt"), CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::shareExclusive | CFile::typeText, &fileException);

        file.WriteString(TEXT("__CR\r"));
        file.WriteString(TEXT("__LF\n"));
        file.WriteString(TEXT("CRLF\r\n"));
        file.WriteString(TEXT("____"));
        file.Flush();
        file.Close();
```

And the resulting output is now:

```
__CR\r
__LF\r\n   //??
CRLF\r\r\n //??
____
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the answer myself: This is a behaviour by design for `CFile::typeText`.

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a499td6y.aspx) states:

> **Text mode** provides special processing for carriage return–linefeed pairs. When you write a newline character (0x0A) to a text-mode CStdioFile object, the byte pair (0x0D, 0x0A) is sent to the file. When you read, the byte pair (0x0D, 0x0A) is translated to a single 0x0A byte.

So in fact I changed the mode from `CFile::typeBinary` to `CFile::typeText` and thus provoking another behaviour. For `CFile::typeBinary` you will not get the additional carriage returns.